# NoMatchingExpectationException for mock object, when testing in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5, mockery

My test method:

```
public function testProjectTmpImageCanBeUploaded(){
    // \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile; 
    $file = m::mock(UploadedFile::class, [
        "getClientOriginalName" => "author",
        "getClientOriginalExtension" => "jpg",
        "isValid" => true,
    ]);

    $file->shouldReceive('move')
        ->once()
        ->with(config('app.tmp_folder_name')."/project", 'author-now.jpg');

    $url = route('upload-project-image');

    $this->call("POST", $url,
        [
            'field' => 'photo',
            'item_name' => 'project',
        ]
        ,[],['file' => $file]);
}
```

Also I have the method, which uses the next code:

```
if ($file->isValid()) {

        $file->move($path, $fileName);// 
    }
```

This code is working well, the parametres are correct, but when I execute the test it fails with the next description:

> [2017-09-07 18:21:49] testing.ERROR: Mockery\Exception\NoMatchingExpectationException: No matching handler found for Mockery_0_Illuminate_Http_UploadedFile::move("C:\OServer\OpenServer\domains\site.local\blog\public/tmp/project/", "project-now.jpg"). Either the method was unexpected or its arguments matched no expected argument list for this method

Does anybody know, what's the problem with this test?

I use Laravel 5.2.45.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you look close you will see in your test you have as 2nd argument `author-now.jpg` but Mockery is giving you error when the 2nd argument is `project-now.jpg` so you should probably update this 2nd argument in your test

Comment: O, thank's for answer, it was a mistake from me. But the problem is still the same( same exception).
` testing.ERROR: Mockery\Exception\NoMatchingExpectationException: No matching handler found for Mockery_0_Illuminate_Http_UploadedFile::move("C:\OServer\OpenServer\domains\site.local\blog\public\/tmp/project/", "project-now.jpg"). Either the method was unexpected or its arguments matched no expected argument list for this method`.

Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: You should make sure both parameters are exactly same, so dd in app in test and compare them

Comment: Thank you! The problem was connected with the extra quote.